# Laravel/Lumen : unexpected '=>'

Tags: laravel, filter, lumen, arrow-functions

I have this code in controller :

```
$myresults = $matches->map(function ($items, $key ) {
            $items['date']=\Carbon\Carbon::parse($items['m_date'])->format("Y-m-d");
            $items['time']=\Carbon\Carbon::parse($items['m_date'])->format("H:i");
            return $items;
        })->groupBy(function ($item, $key) {
            return \Carbon\Carbon::parse($item["date"])->format("Y-m-d");
        })->map(function ($item, $key) {
            return ["date"=> $key, "matches"=> $item];
        })->values();

        $results = collect($myresults)->filter(fn  ($item)=> collect($item['matches'])->filter(fn ($match)=> collect($match['predect'])->filter(fn ($predect)=> $predect['user_id']!=$id)));
```

it works before fine ,after I deploy it to website it gaves me this error : `syntax error, unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW), expecting ')'`

Comment: Your production server isn't running on php 7.4.... is it?
Arrow functions were introduced in 7.4
https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arrow.php

Comment: Please share more details - this does not look related to Laravel to me after all

Comment: @JordanCasey it was 7.3... I changed it now to 7.4.16  it is worked many thanks'

Comment: @NicoHaase I added some details on controller

Comment: Please share more details about your approach to resolve the problem. Which of these lines causes the problem? That code would be way more readable if you used multiple lines

Comment: @NicoHaase it is solved by changing Php version to 7.4.16

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your production server running on php 7.4?

Arrow functions were introduced in 7.4

https://php.net/manual/en/functions.arrow.php

Answer (score 0):

as JordanCasey mention the arrow function introduced in Php 7.4.. version ,therefore after I upgrade the php version in erver it is worked correctly.

Many Thanks for @JordanCasey